# Difference between 2 meetings overlapping each other

Tags: properties, vbscript, calendar, outlook

I'm having this issue:
I'm using VBS to extract all meetings from our conference rooms. 
Sometimes I get from the same room 2 meetings that overlap each other for a certain amount of time. But, outlook shows only one of them.

I've tried to check all the `item.fields` to see what seems to be the criteria by which a meeting is shown in shared calendar, or not, but all seems to be the same for both.

I would have uploaded my code here, but it is very long, about 350 code lines.

So, my question is, what property is used by outlook to show to other people in a shared calendar, a meeting, if it overlaps with another one?

Comment: Additional info: many of the overlapping appointments are recurrences. maybe i don`t retrieve the recurred instance, but the original one? in this case, the question transforms in how can i get an instance of an recurred appointment?

Comment: feel free to upload your great 350 lines of code - SO puts scrollbars so it doesn't take too much space on screen

Answer (score 2):

I`ve found the answer.
Microsoft uses this model for recurrent appointments:
When a recurring event is created, the item.isRecurring is set to True.
then the colection occurrences is added to item, and reccuring pattern object.
If you delete or modify one or more occurrences, anther object is added to occurences, exception. All deleted, or modified occurrences can be found here.
the strange thing is that even if an occurence is deleted, you can still find it as active, and thus, overlaying with the appointments created afterwards.
The trick is to check all the way, even in exceptions, in order to be able to get same view as in Outlook.

if you need additional details, pm me.